# Parameter" does not exist warning

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, game-development

**The Context:**
I'm currently creating a melee combo system for my 2D RPG. The first time a player attacks will trigger the first attack animation and if the player chooses to attack a second time, it ill trigger the second attack animation. I got the system to work by calling an attack function that passes a string parameter depending on which animation I need to be played.

So the ComboOrder function will be called every frame to order the animations and once the player presses the "E" key, the Attack function will be called with either "Attack-1" or "Attack-2".

**The Problem:** The code and animations work fine however, after many changes to other parts of the game I noticed, I get a warning every time I press the "E" key. What I changed was completely unrelated ti this so I don't see a connection from that to the warning.

[image]

```
Parameter" does not exist
```

**Solutions I have tried:** I've searched the web for answers, however, none of them fit my issue. It seems that Unity thinks I'm passing the string " which would indicate a syntax error but I've double-checked my code and I can't find anything of sorts. I've also heard that it has been a bug in Unity but they never told how to fix it. Is there anything I can do if that were the case?

Here's the code:

```
    void ComboOrder() {
    if (comboIndex == 1)
    {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)) // Attack Input
            {
                Attack("Attack-1");
                comboIndex++;
            }
    } else if (comboIndex == 2) {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)) // Attack Input
            {
                Attack("Attack-2");
                comboIndex--;
            }
    }
}

public void Attack(string attack)
{
    animator.SetTrigger(attack);
}
```

And here are the Animator settings for the player:

[image: Animator Settings]
[image: Animator Settings Inspector]

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the code as a code snippet rather than as an image please. That way it's easier for people try out your code and help.
Have you tried changing `public void Attack(string attack = "")` to `public void Attack(string attack)`? I don't see why this should affect things, but worth seeing if that changes the error.
Is anywhere else in your code calling the Attack function without a parameter specified?

Comment: Please show the animator settings

Comment: @RossGurbutt I’m not currently at my desk and I’m using the StackExchange app so I can’t add snippets but I’ll let you know as soon as I get home. I do remember now that you mention it, another instance where the function is called however I’m not sure if it passes any parameters with it. The warning points to this line so I assumed the problem was around here.

Comment: @BugFinder I’m not currently at home but I’ll add it as soon as I get home.

Comment: @RossGurbutt I tried what you suggested, replacing `public void Attack(string attack = "")` with  `public void Attack(string attack)` but it made no difference. Upon further investigation I realized the Warning is only given when the first animation is played "Attack-1", the second animation gives no error or warning.

Comment: @BugFinder I've updated the post to include an image of the settings.

Comment: Then that suggests attack is called somewhere else or a set trigger is

Answer (score 0):

So after not being able to work on the game for about two weeks, I came back to take a closer look and realized it was what you said, there was an animation event calling the function without passing a parameter and since it was not coded, I never caught it. Thank you to everybody who helped.